# Why natural order is speedy?

Tags: mongodb

In [this slides](http://www.slideshare.net/lennartkoopmann/capped-collections), the author said that capped collection is perfect for logging because it is speedy by natural ordering. Could you please explain for me why it is speedy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natural order means "return the data in the same order it is stored on disk, no sorting necessary". This is fast. Unfortunately, it usually is no "meaningful" order at all. To get a meaningful order, you have to sort by data in a field, and this implies either in-memory sorting, or random access through an index (which is slower than sequential access).

In a capped collection, natural order happens to be the same order as document creation.

So if you want log entries in chronological order, a capped collection can provide that cheaply.

Answer (score 2):

(Unless explicitly created) there is no index on the collection, which means insertion is very quick. Think of it as appending to a list, as opposed to inserting an element to a sorted data structure.